# JMeter: How to specify the users.csv file in the command line

Tags: jmeter

When using JMeter from the command line, I get the following error in my log:

```
2014/08/05 14:29:43 ERROR - jmeter.config.CSVDataSet: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/home/stew/YOU_FORGOT_TO_SPECIFY_USERS_CSV_FILE.csv (No such file or directory)
```

The user.csv file is in the same directory as the testplan.jmx file. Is there an option to specify the file in the command line?

Regards,
Wolf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use relative file name for path then it should work, as per reference documentation:

> Filename  Name of the file to be read. Relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the active test plan. For distributed testing, the CSV file must be stored on the server host system in the correct relative directory to where the jmeter server is started.

For another solution, Have a look at :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P

You use this function in CSV dataset :
${__P(resdir)} 
and on command line:

> -Jresdir=your path to csv file

Answer (score 0):

I was using Jmeter to test load Moodle and used options -Jresdir and -Jusersfile options to pass usersfile name